# bundle install problem: mysql.h is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, mysql2

in my mac OSX 10.6 32 bit, I can install mysql2 gem quite easily, but not in mini mac 10.6 64bit server.

I have installed MySQL 5.5.11 in troublesome server, while in my home mac MySQL 5.5.0.m2
Somehow when I run bundle install, in server it tries to install mysql2.0.3.2 while in home mysql2.0.2.6

Please don't tell me to

env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" sudo gem install mysql2 --version '= 0.2.6' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

I tried that, doesn't work.

Included /usr/local/mysql/bin in $PATH does not help as well.

Error code:

```
    Installing mysql2 (0.3.2) with native extensions /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:511:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `each'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `build_extensions'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:159:in `install'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in `install'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.12/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I tried all the solutions posted here, but was not lucky. I reinstalled mysql with homebrew a couple of times and still no luck. Then I came across a blog post with a solution.

I edited the mysql_config file in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/bin` and removed 
the W-compiler options 
`-Wno-null-conversion` and 
`-Wno-unused-private-field`
for cflags and cxxflags.

This solved the problem with `gem install mysql2` and `bundle install`

Reference: http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2013/05/gem-install-mysql2-missing-mysqlh-on-os.html

Comment: Confirmed with OS X 10.8.3, XCode 4.6.3 and MySQL 5.6.12.

Comment: Had the same problem and this solved my problem. Could these flags been introduced by mistake? I have compiled the `mysql2` gem in the past without any problems, using a brewed mysql.

Comment: Worked perfectly on 10.8 / 5.6.12

Comment: THANK YOU! Where can we report/fix this bug?

Comment: Solved the problem with OS X 10.8.4 and MySQL 5.6.12. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same problem, but my MySQL was from the OSX installer available on their site, not brew or fink installs.  The fix above worked perfectly, but I had to edit this file: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Answer (score 28):

I did a bundle install on a redmine repo and got the same error message :

> mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.

Running Fedora 16 64 bits, all I did was install `mysql-devel` (development package) from the distro rpm and the problem was solved!

So I think you could just

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

or apt-get the missing devel package.

Comment: This is not related to OS X.

Comment: Well it helped me... so I'm grateful he/she posted it!

Comment: Thanks. For information, with Fedora 19 (mariadb), obviously, it's mariadb-devel

Answer (score 8):

for people who didn't use brew to install mysql and use mysql 5.6 and higher:

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657304/mysql-h-is-missing-ruby-on-rails-osx)

you need to edit `mysql_config` which was placed in my case here: `/usr/local/mysql-5.6.12-osx10.7-x86_64/bin`

and change `cflags` and `cxxflags` to:

```
cflags="-I$pkgincludedir  -Wall -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DDBUG_OFF " #note: end space!
cxxflags="-I$pkgincludedir  -Wall -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DDBUG_OFF " #note: end space!
```

after this manipulations

```
$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13'
```

goes flawlessly

Comment: This worked for me on OSX 10.9.4 trying to install mysql2 0.3.11

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me in mavericks with gem install mysql. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Ok guys for me the solution was:

```
$ sudo brew install mysql

$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- \
  --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib \
  --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

source: http://wonko.com/post/how-to-install-the-mysqlruby-gem-on-mac-os-x-leopard

OR :

```
$sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- \
  --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib \
  --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

If your mysql version is 64Bits

After that i had a lot of problems because if i want to create the database:

```
$: bundle exec rake db:reset
```

i was receiving this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Users/workdreamer/Sites/cavortify/implementation/cavortify/mysql/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Users/workdreamer/Sites/cavortify/implementation/cavortify/mysql/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

The solution is: On your gemfile add: gem "ruby-mysql"

Ok, one day and a half to find the solution.

Have a nice day!

Comment: You shouldn't need to sudo brew

Comment: ruby-mysql does not use the native files you built.

Answer (score 2):

This method is for Rails 3.1.0 (and hopefully up) on 64 bit machine. I used on Ruby-1.9.2-p180.

This blog answered it: http://www.tatvartha.com/2010/10/installing-mysql-gem-with-bundler-on-snow-leopard/

Basically, the method above: $ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

may work, but without bundler.

To do it with bundler, first must run this on terminal:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Note "mysql2" not "mysql" as shown in that blog.

That adds a config to ~/.bundle/config file

Then add this to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

That is the same with telling bundler to run the command on top of this post.

Comment: Just a protip: since I used Homebrew to install Mysql, the line should look something like this: bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/bin/mysql_config

Comment: or you can find it like $ `find / -name mysql_config 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get this to work was to install the x64 version of mysql. I just used the .dmg located here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and it worked like a charm. Wish I could get the 4 hours back it took to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on my Mac OSX Lion:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/mysql/mysql  -pipe -fPIC    -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT  -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/lib/mysql/mysql --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/include/mysql/mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

[This blog answered it](http://www.conandalton.net/2010/10/gem-install-mysql-should-be-easy-on-mac.html).

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the result of first installing MySql via the downloadable binary. It was originally installed at version 5.5.28. I then attempted to install via homebrew. Brew installed version 5.6.x. HOWEVER in the process of installing via homebrew, the symlink for /usr/local/mysql was still pointed to 5.5.28.

Update your symlink to whichever version was installed via homebrew.

ex: /usr/local/mysql -> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/

This could be just part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For mariadb:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient18 libmariadbclient-dev
```

Then

```
gem install mysql2
```

could be successfully installed.

Comment: apt-get is not available on Mac OS.

Comment: Yes @ArtemZinnatullin -- it's for Ubuntu users for those people who are here trying to find solution by googling 'mysql.h is missing' as me. I lost some time to find a solution and want to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that gcc is installed. If it isn't, you will get that same error message.

You can check the results/log file it mentions for more clues as to the cause.

Comment: Turns out I was mistakenly added a spacebar in my archflag command.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this wherever I can--hopefully it will help someone and save them a lot of time.

I dug through 2 days worth of the internet and Stack Overflow, and it wasn't until I found [this link](http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2013/05/gem-install-mysql2-missing-mysqlh-on-os.html) and then starting working through [this ticket for mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/383) that I actually resolved the issue.

With my setup (as explained in the ticket), the compiler switches of -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-unused-private-field would break and give me an error that wasn't exactly correct, which was:

```
mysql.h is missing. please check your installation of mysql and try again
```

Answer (score 0):

For those on Fedora 21, and you already installed mysql-devel:

```
yum install redhat-rpm-config
```

solved the problem for me. see:
[redhat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/5.4_Technical_Notes/redhat-rpm-config.html)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6 /usr/local/mysql
```

I got stumped by this issue for almost 2 days and reinstalled `xcode` and `mysql` so many times.

I originally had `mysql@5.6` installed using `brew`, but the `bundle install` command kept failing because it could not find a `mysql` installation. Error output below:

```
libmysqlclient is missing. You may need to 'brew install mysql' or 'port install mysql', and try again.
```

However, using @Kevin Boedigheimer's answer helped fixed the problem i.e. I linked the installed `mysql@5.6` to `/usr/local/mysql`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.6 /usr/local/mysql
```

N.B: In case your mysql directory is somewhere else, you can find it using:

```
find / -name 'mysql*5.6' 2&> /dev/null

# '2&> /dev/null' ensures you have just the output you need
```