# gem install pg --with-pg-config works, bundle fails

Tags: postgresql, rubygems, bundler, pg

WhenI run (as root)

```
gem install pg -v '0.12.0' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

I get the following output:

```
#-> gem instal pg -v '0.12.0' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.12.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for pg-0.12.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for pg-0.12.0...
#->
```

When I run bundle install:

```
Installing pg (0.12.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/simpletrac/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-    0.12.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/www/simpletrac/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.12.0/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing pg (0.12.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.12.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have libpq-fe.h installed at /usr/pgsql-9.1/include/libpq-fe.h. So, I tried

```
gem install pg -v '0.12.0' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config --with-pg-lib=/usr/pgsql-9.1/include/libpq-fe.h but still no go.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I have installed postgresql91-devel and ruby-devel.  Running CentOS 6.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Have you tried running this before running `bundle install`?

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

See http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_config.html

Comment: If you're using MacOS + MacPorts, see Lester's post for the solution.

Comment: I have same error but I am using mysql database. What will be command pls ??

Comment: This seems to have the answer for MySql: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9360181/171933

Comment: Worked like a charm on CentOS 6!
Just needed to run also a `yum install postgresql-devel` before the whole installation fully succeeded!

Comment: Also `--with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-<version>` handles both config and lib.

Answer (score 23):

In case somebody used macports to install postgres and are having problems finding their pg_config, try this:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config
```

I hope this helps somebody save some time. Cheers!

Answer (score 22):

If you are not sure where your `pg_config` is, and assuming you are on Linux or Mac, you can run the following command:

```
which pg_config
```

This will return   `/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config`

Now use this path as

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

And we are ready to go `bundle install`

Answer (score 11):

## Copy & Paste:

```bash
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=`which pg_config` && bundle
```

---

## Details:

> Visit for more information:
>
> - http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-config.1.html
> - https://github.com/nlopes/pg/blob/master/readme-os_x.rdoc
>
> > *The first thing you should do is ensure that the 'pg_config' tool that comes with Postgres is in your path. If it isn't, or the one that's first in your path isn't the one that was installed with the Postgres you want to build against, you can specify the path to it with the –with-pg-config option.*
> >
> > **Source:** https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/1f274f68c16f1af1c642db1b9d3d28aef169dc84/ext/extconf.rb#L27

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem, fixed by installing libpq-dev.

Ref: https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/83/help-gem-install-pg-failed-on-opensuse-103

Answer (score 5):

You can get this error if you have pg_config installed but its not in any path. You can add it to your PATH env in your ~/.bashrc.

For example.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin
```

Comment: Could this be a result of installing from source instead of a package manager? Worked for me anyways - Just curious of why I encountered the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The Postgres gem can't find the Postgres configuration file. You need to tell it where it is. The most enjoyable solution to this in my opinion is to skip Brew and MacPorts and just use the Postgres app. Download and install from here:

http://postgresapp.com/

Now add the bin folder to your path:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

You may also wish to add this to your ~/.bash_profile

Now install the gem:

```
gem install pg
```

it should go smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm on Mac and i use Homebrew, so to fix this issue i just installed postgresql with brew:

```
brew install postgresql
```

And then installed the gem.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this to fix mine on OS X:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/:$PATH
```

And I had to do it despite the fact that I already had this in my path:

```
[user@foo ~] which psql84
/opt/local/bin/psql84

[user@foo ~] ls -altrh /opt/local/bin/psql84 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    36B Dec  7 02:15 /opt/local/bin/psql84 ->  /opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/psql
```

I hope that helps another Mac user with this problem.

Comment: Thanks I have tested this solution on Mac Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
yum install libpqxx-devel
```

It works with Postgr9.2.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Arch Linux, and was having similar problems. Used `sudo pacman -S libpqxx` and reran then installed the pg gem and then ran `bundle install` again, and this time it finally worked!

Comment: I am using Arch Linux as well and this solved my issue!

Comment: 2016, postgresql 9.5 and pg 0.18.4 doesn't seem to work with the solution mentioned (I am also using arch linux).

Answer (score 2):

Somes cases on UBUNTU

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

On CentOS 7

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://community.stuk.io/t/installing-rails-on-windows-complete-guide/39) suggested using:

```
gem install pg --pre
```

I couldn't get the `pg gem` to install for days,but this method finally worked for me. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When do you use postgresapp on Mac, read the http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html documentation and Configure your $PATH. Before this try run the bundle install again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have postgress installed. if not install it first. Using terminal for example.

```
brew install postgresql
```

After that run

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install pg -v '0.17.1'
```

Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

in OSX, first install pg:

```
brew install postgresql
```

second, do gem install:

```
gem install pg --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

you can then run `bundle install`

Answer (score -1):

I am using mac and didn't want to install postgresql locally.

Installing **libpq** and setting the bundler config worked for me.

[Reference link](https://michaelrigart.be/install-pg-ruby-gem-without-postgresql/)