# rails - postgres error: Reason: Incompatible library version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, osx-snow-leopard

I am stuck with the setup of Ruby (1.9.3), Rails and Postgres  (9.0.8) on my Mac (10.6.8).
Everytime when I run `rails console` I get the following error:

```
/Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': dlopen(/Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libssl.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libssl.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8 - /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle  
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/pg-0.13.2/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /Users/dc/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/http/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/dc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I really don't know how to fix this. I already tried installing a different Postgres version and I still get the same error.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. If that helps....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this also, but was able to fix it following the instructions on [python pip install psycopg2 install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538249/python-pip-install-psycopg2-install-error).

First, make sure you have the [most recent version of OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#MISC1) installed:

```
MacBook Pro:~> openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010
built on: Mon Jan  3 17:26:21 PST 2011
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -DMD32_REG_T=int -Wall
OPENSSLDIR: "/opt/local/etc/openssl"
```

...and note the OPENSSLDIR. On my system, it's in /opt/local/, because I installed it via MacPorts. I just needed to update the symlinks in /usr/lib/ for libssl.dylib and libcrypto.dylib so that they pointed to the correct versions in /opt/local/lib instead of the old version in usr/lib:

```
MacBook Pro:~> ls -la /usr/lib/libssl.dylib 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  33 Aug 17 12:25 /usr/lib/libssl.dylib -> /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
MacBook Pro:~> ls -la /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  36 Aug 17 12:28 /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib -> /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

You can create the links by using the `ln` command:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/postgres/install/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
sudo ln -s /path/to/postgres/install/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
```

Comment: nice, i finally got it working. I set the symlinks as described and set the bundle config...

Answer (score 5):

Symlinking the files as above didn't work for me. pg would always look at libssl-0.9.8.dylib.

This question contains the right answer it seems: [gem install pg --with-pg-config works, bundle fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234960/gem-install-pg-with-pg-config-works-bundle-fails)

It boils down to

`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config`

(or whichever pg you are targeting)

followed by `gem uninstall pg` and then `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

In one project this solution ("gem install & uninstall pg") was fine.

But in another project, that uses the same rails and Postgres version, I had to be explicit with version in gemfile to make it work:

```
  gem 'pg', '0.14.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install new PostgreSQL version (i've used homebrew)

```
brew install postgres
```

Then reinstall the gem pg:

```
gem uninstall pg
gem install pg
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no such thing as "postgre" and `brew install postgre` will produce only an error. I assume you meant "postgres" or "PostgreSQL"? Also, the original poster said they'd already tried a new Pg version.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here that worked for me:
https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/109

Comment: Could you please include a summary of the solution? This will make your answer more accessible, plus it will still retain value if the linked page disappears.

Comment: `export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` works for me