# python pip install psycopg2 install error

Tags: python, postgresql, pip

I did a simple `pip install psycopg2` on mac system. It installed fine, but when I try to use psycopg2 I get the error:

```
Reason: Incompatible library version: _psycopg.so requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libssl.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8
```

`pip freeze` shows `psycopg2==2.4.5` just right. I have installed psycopg2 on several virtualenvs but this is the first time I am seeing such error. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, same results. Please help

Comment: update you dist. you need fresher `libssl`

Comment: libssl comes installed by postgres by default. I am using 9.1

Comment: What does otool -L <packName> say?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem after upgrading to Mountain Lion.

Instead of copying libssl.* files per Slack's suggestion, make sure that `/usr/lib/libssl.dylib` is actually a soft link to the most up-to-date version of the library.

E.g., on my machine, `ls -l /usr/lib/libssl*` gives:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    46B Jun 27 15:24 /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib -> /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    27B Jul 30 10:31 /usr/lib/libssl.dylib -> /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

If `libssl.dylib` doesn't link to the version that the error version mentions, make sure you have that version of the library, and then make sure `/usr/lib/libssl.dylib` points to it, and not an older version.

If the link doesn't exist, create it like so

```
sudo ln -s library_to_link_to link_to_create
```

using, of course, the proper locations for your machine. For me, this turned out to be:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
```

**Edit**:

It seems like some are having trouble with part of my solution. Namely, deleting these important libraries even temporarily causes problems with the operating system.

Per [Purrell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538249/python-pip-install-psycopg2-install-error/12397173#12397173), make sure you include the `-fs` flags when you use the `ln` command, which helps ensure that the libraries don't go missing for a short period of time. E.g.,

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```

Comment: works fine, **warning** be careful when messing with those files, i made a mistake that broke the entire os.

Comment: @bosco Yes, the same thing happened to me. I was on this very thread, and screwed up the OS (Snow Leopard, fixed with Mountain Lion upgrade USB). For other people reading this, I believe you need to ln -fs ... Do not delete the symlink first. I don't exactly understand why this happens. I suppose some process can potentially be using the lib when it gets deleted? Maybe deleting and relinking libs is roulette. If anyone knows more please explain.

Answer (score 53):

The accepted answer here is correct (except I think it must be ln -fs , in fact I think it might even risk destabalizing your OS if not (?)). After bumping into this and dealing with it I just want to collect the full solution for this issue and the other lib problem (libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib) you will run into for Postgres 9.* on Mountain Lion and Snow Leopard, and perhaps other systems. This also blocked me from running psql, which complained about the same two libs.

Essentially there are two later-version libs needed in `/usr/lib`, libssl and libcrypto. You can find the needed versions of these libs in the Postgres lib directory.

- If you're OSX and installed the Enterprise DB version of Postgres this will be in `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib`.
- For other install types of Postgres, look for the lib directory inside the Postgress install directory, e.g., for Postgress.app, find the lib directory in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib`,
- for brew somewhere in `/usr/local/Cellar`,
- on *nix, wherever your install is. But see first on *nix if your distro has later versions just through the package manager.

First copy the latest of these two libs from the Postgres lib directory to `/usr/lib`:

```
sudo cp /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
sudo cp /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
```

Then update (or create) the /usr/lib symlinks for this libs. Either way the command is `ln -fs`:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```

Should be fixed. Pretty sure ln -fs is better than deleting the symlink and remaking it, so there is less chance of libssl being unfindable by something that needs it for the time it is not present (it does the same thing; it first deletes the symlink if it's already there, just faster than you can type it). Always wary of messing around on /usr/lib.

Comment: +1 @purrell. At the time of asking this question there wasn't much solutions available around, so I bumped it on SO. Though unfortunate that people ran into same trouble, its great to see them sharing their solutions. Thanks for detailed explanation. Will help many out there. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. What I fail to understand though, is why I did not have this problem a week ago with exactly the same package versions in another virtualenv (which is what the OP suggests too)?

Comment: This applies to OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) as well. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to have completely broken Chrome for me. (Google Chrome v35.0.1916.153, Mac OS X 10.7.5) 
``Dyld Error Message:  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib, Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find: /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture``. Safari is also failing to load https with the error: ``com.apple.mdworker: /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture``

Answer (score 42):

Worked for me:

```
env LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib' pip install psycopg2
```

Source: [Can't install psycopg2 with pip in virtualenv on Mac OS X 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678408/cant-install-psycopg2-with-pip-in-virtualenv-on-mac-os-x-10-7/42264168#42264168)

Comment: LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib' pip install psycopg2 resolved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me as well, though I did install postgresql@9.5 using brew before running this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

On OSX 10.11, El Capitan, solution with replacing symlinks reported `Operation not permitted`. Solution that worked for me was using brew and setting up DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. So:

```
brew install openssl
```

Find where openssl brew libs are located (`brew --prefix openssl` can help), start searching from directory `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl`. In my case it is in `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib`

Finally set up DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, i.e. add a line like this into .bash_profile :

```
# replace location of lib files with folder name you found in previous step
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib
```

UPDATE: More generic/better alternatives are (thanks to @dfrankow):

- to use brew to find openssl location (a note, brew can be slow): `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib`
- for development purposes maybe it is better to use `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` instead - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146274/is-it-ok-to-use-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-whats-the-dynamic-library-s)

Restart shell, or just `source ~/.bash_profile`, reinstall psycopg2:

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install psycopg2
```

and test if it works:

```
$ python -c"import psycopg2  ;   print('psycopg2 is now ok')"
```

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/33032963/34935: you can also try the more generic: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib`. And, you can also use `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` instead, to not interfere with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pip install psycopg2

Answer (score 2):

When trying to do a syncdb Postgres 9.1 and /psycopg2/_psycopg.so added a further error:

Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libcrypto.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
Reason: Incompatible library version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8

Solved by copying these six (6) files from:

LOCAL:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/

libssl.1.0.0.dylib

libssl.a

libssl.dylib

libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib

libcrypto.a

libcrypto.dylib

to: LOCAL:/usr/lib

This was on Mac OSx 10.8.1 with a web in a virtualenv (1.8.2) and pgAdmin (1.14.3). Inside the virtualenv is:

Django==1.4

psycopg2==2.4.5

... etc... and now back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the libcryto and libss version 1.0.0 resides below:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

so the commands that fix my problem is:

```
sudo ln -fs /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
sudo ln -fs /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

my friend, just copy libssl.* files from PostgreSQL lib directory to /usr/lib and relaunch your application in this case all things will be perfect ^_^

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!  For reference, on OSX 10.8 the PostgreSQL lib directory Slack refers to was `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/`.

Comment: This actually won't solve it. The symlinks need to be changed also.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Mavericks, it worked to just copy the two dylib and relaunch Python:

```
cp /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/
cp /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncomfortable copying libraries into your system directory, you can use the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to force the OS to search Postgres's library directory for libssl. E.g.:

```
$ DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib pip install psycopg2
```

(documented under the `dyld` man page).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on my Mac OS High Sierra.

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/chicha/Projects/CTMR/sample_registration/romans_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

But after "pip install postgres" it's work fine.
According to pip show - "postgres is a high-value abstraction over psycopg2".
While installing it's also installed psycopg2-binary and psycopg2-pool.
So, all together they have repaired the situation somehow.