# Django can't find libssl on OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, django, macos, postgresql

I'm trying to get Django running on OS X Mavericks and I've encountered a bunch of errors along the way, the latest way being that when run`python manage.py runserver` to see if everything works, I get this error, which I believe means that it misses libssl:

> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so Reason: image not found

I have already upgraded Python to 2.7.6 with the patch that handles some of the quirks of Mavericks.

Any ideas?

Full traceback:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 93, in inner_run
>       self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
>       num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 28, in get_validation_errors
>       from django.db import models, connection
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/**init**.py", line 40, in 
>       backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/**init**.py", line 34, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in **getitem**
>       backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
>       return import_module('.base', backend_name)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 14, in 
>       from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.creation import DatabaseCreation
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/creation.py", line 1, in 
>       import psycopg2.extensions
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 50, in 
>       from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
>     Reason: image not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

psycopg2 is missing. Postgresql database adapter for Python.

You need to reinstall Postgresql. You're on a mac, so install it using `brew`.

```
brew install postgresql
```

If brew outputs that it's already installed, uninstall it and reinstall it again.

Comment: I had installed the postgres.app (www.postgresapp.com) and I uninstalled that one and reinstalled via Homebrew, to no avail. Same error.

Comment: what if you define the environment variable like this: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.*/lib` replace 9.* with the postgresql current version

Comment: Yay, defining the environment variable works! Thanks a lot, struggling for hours with this.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me.

```
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

This will recreate correctly all the links to libssl 1.0 which was already installed.

Comment: didn't fix it for me. :(

Comment: It worked for me under Mac OS X El Capitan, thanks! Django was looking for openssl-1.0.0 but now it uses openssl-1.0.2d_1 (I did a `brew uninstall openssl` and `brew install openssl` before that)

Comment: Thanks this fixed my problem on El Capitan. Why does this work?

Comment: This no longer works with recent Homebrew, instead you get `Warning: Refusing to link: openssl`. Instead use `CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip ...`

Comment: @DanielleMadeley Can you please provide the complete solution ? Seems like there's more to that command.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it's `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` that is missing. Mavericks comme with `libssl 0.9.8`. You need to install libssl via homebrew.

If loaderpath points to `/usr/lib/`, you also need to symlink libssl from `/usr/local/Cell/openssl/lib/` into `/usr/lib`.

Comment: For a more general answer (not _Homebrew_ specific) see [this SO question about Python and PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538249/python-pip-install-psycopg2-install-error)

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened to me because I was using **posqgressapp**. This is probably related to sandboxing.

Delete the posqgressapp and install postgress using brew solved my problem.

Install Postgress using HomeBrew: 
 
http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/

Unable to open psql on Mavericks:
 
https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/137

Answer (score 1):

Installing the full PostgreSQL server on my OSX laptop bothers me. Uninstall is clunky and now you have a pretty rocking DB server just sitting unused just for the libraries.

I know others have posted against using Postgres.app but I love it. Its clean and easy to use. The key is to remember that its just a folder with all the necessary libraries inside to help when building Psycopg2 on your OSX box. Just make sure add something to your path so you can find the libraries like:

$ PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/

(Alter, of course based upon the version of Postgres.app that you installed.)

Once you get your psycopg2  compiled you simply drag Postgres.app to the trash and its gone. Easy peasy.

I wasted a lot of time with all kind of errors and psycopg2 on both OSX & Linux, so I threw this together:

http://www.codychamberlain.com/posts/installing-psycopg2-on-osx/

Comment: of course for this specific question you'd possibly setup some symlinks for update the PATH to this location: /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/lib

Comment: link to blog post is dead.