# Psycopg2 installation for OS X and Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I would like to use the `PostGreSQL` database with Django.
I first installed the driver `psycopg2` with `pip` and `virtualenv`:

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/
$ pip install psycopg2
[...]
  Successfully installed psycopg2
  Cleaning up...
$
```

I have done the following configuration in Django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'xx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

But when I try to create the schema with `syncdb` I have the following error:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
  raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen([...]/Code/env/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: [...]Code/env/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Do you know why the `libssl` is not loaded and how can I fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Found the solution thanks to Purrell post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12397173/1630586

Comment: possible duplicate of [python pip install psycopg2 install error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538249/python-pip-install-psycopg2-install-error)