# "ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module" after migrate

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 440, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 478, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1183, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_long_column_names())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1588, in _check_long_column_names
    connection = connections[db]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
```

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

BTW, my psycopg2 is working fine as a standalone module.

Comment: As a note this kind of question is not going to get much attention. Maybe take some time to give some details instead of a F* huge stacktrace.

Comment: Please share your code and configuration

Comment: @Finwood this is the error I get when I run "python manage.py migrate"
any pointer?

MattWritesCode , really sorry. This is my first question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django is unable to detect psycopg2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289307/django-is-unable-to-detect-psycopg2)

Answer (score 1):

this statement solved everything: export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=''

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more precisely with your Question. 
First of all, your error is :

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module
```

When do you get this error? (what command you run?)
What is your settings.py looking like?

Also you should format your Question better, it's a pain to read this Traceback!

I know this is more a comment then an answer, but i don't had enough reputation for that.

Comment: sorry for wrong formatting. this is my first question.
please ignore that this time and read the log. It's kinda urgent.

Comment: Well you still should start with giving us the settings.py, there is a part like this 

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'name of your database',
            'USER': 'name of your database user',
            'PASSWORD': 'password super secret',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wg8gDQBj

This is the automatic one which is created by Django. I just added extra DataBase.

Comment: also, it was running fine till last night. Today I installed 'requests' and hell broke lose. Any relation b/w these?

Comment: your settings.py looks okay. take a look here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351055/psycopg2-installation-for-os-x-and-django and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538249/python-pip-install-psycopg2-install-error/12397173#12397173

Comment: everything is getting resolved if im using only the default database.
its adding the second database thats creating the problem