# ln: /usr/lib/libssl.dylib: Operation not permitted OSX

Tags: macos

I'm trying to create a symbolic link to /usr/lib but I seems I have not permission, included with root. The system is return that the operations is not permitted.

With Yosemite I worked fine, but with El Capitan it broke :/

Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 7):

I had some issues using the linked subl command for Sublime text 3.  It was the same issue you encountered, I believe.

Apparently, usr/local does not have the same controls on it. So instead of

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

as recommended by Sublime docs,

it was more along the lines of:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" usr/local/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it using this command in the Recovery mode:

```
csrutil disable
```

Apple has created a new flag named "restricted" which limit the access to files and folders that execute in this mode. Then, I copy the files and created the symbolic links again and It works.

```
sudo cp /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib
sudo cp /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib

sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.dylib
sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib
```

Comment: Local customizations like this really belong in /usr/local (see notthehoff's answer). Apple's now enforcing this as a rule. Disabling system integrity protection so you can continue doing it wrong is a bad idea on several levels

Comment: Turning off rootless mode is quite reckless and dangerous. There are better solutions that also do not require to redo this with every OS update.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to mess with system directories any more due security reasons and complexity and sensitivity of the security disabling process ([rootless mode and csrutil disable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really)).

If you have issues with development libraries used from terminal/shell programs (rails, django, python, ruby, php, ...) - I would suggest following alternative:

- install new version of library somewhere/somehow (e.g. brew install ...)
- setup DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in .bash_profile to location where new lib*.dylib(s) are located
- restart shell
- reinstall/recompile the library which needed different version of system library - new version libraries should be found and linked

For example check python->postgres-driver->openssl/libssl.dylib on   https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034764/565525) - issue was `Incompatible library version: _psycopg.so requires version 1.0.0 or later ...`.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to do is redirect to the original binary, not changing the contents of `/usr/lib/`. Running `csrutil disable` is **very** bad and dangerous behaviour, it's called 'rootless' for a reason.

If you get an error like:

```
dlopen(/Users/{your_username}/Library/R/4.0/library/sf/libs/sf.so, 6):
Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Then the solution would be to:

1. Find `libpq.5.dylib` on your system, because it is definitely somewhere:

   ```sh
   ~ % sudo find / -name libpq.5.dylib
   # /usr/local/opt/libpq/lib/libpq.5.dylib
   ```
2. Use that file to redirect using `install_name_tool`:

   ```
    sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/opt/libpq/lib/libpq.5.dylib /Users/{your_username}/Library/R/4.0/library/sf/libs/sf.so
   ```