# install psycopg2 failing python 3.7

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, python-3.7

I am following this tutorial - https://medium.com/@qazi/how-to-deploy-a-django-app-to-heroku-in-2018-the-easy-way-48a528d97f9c

so far I've:

- built my Django app and ran locally - works perfectly
- wrote Procfile with content
  `web: gunicorn project_name.wsgi`
- imported django_heroku to settings

I need to install psycopg2 so I ran `pip install psycopg2`

but getting the error

```
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/niamhtohill/ios_dev/vf_api/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/kk/0xnrjqj950qdky6pkv1dws4r0000gn/T/pip-install-q5q1ago2/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kk/0xnrjqj950qdky6pkv1dws4r0000gn/T/pip-install-q5q1ago2/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/kk/0xnrjqj950qdky6pkv1dws4r0000gn/T/pip-wheel-3u2cfbpc --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /private/var/folders/kk/0xnrjqj950qdky6pkv1dws4r0000gn/T/pip-install-q5q1ago2/psycopg2/
  Complete output (144 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100005 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100005 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/include/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=100005 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/include/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
  psycopg/pqpath.c:135:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                  PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  psycopg/pqpath.c:1712:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
      ret = 1;
            ^
  psycopg/pqpath.c:1817:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                  PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

...
...
....
...
...
...
...
...
...

/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/niamhtohill/ios_dev/vf_api/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/kk/0xnrjqj950qdky6pkv1dws4r0000gn/T/pip-install-q5q1ago2/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kk/0xnrjqj950qdky6pkv1dws4r0000gn/T/pip-install-q5q1ago2/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/kk/0xnrjqj950qdky6pkv1dws4r0000gn/T/pip-record-t0kpmijs/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/niamhtohill/ios_dev/vf_api/venv/bin/../include/site/python3.7/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
```

really feel like im going round in circles! have retried the steps out 10 times

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:heroku]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pip install psycopg2 install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538249/python-pip-install-psycopg2-install-error)

Comment: yes on Mac running Mojave and in a virtual environment

Comment: this is for deploying to Heroku as mentioned in the tutorial linked. The step is git push heroku master

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. my requirements.txt file contains Psycopg binary but not Psycopg. this is what is breaking

Answer (score 4):

Instead of **pip install psycopg2** try to run **pip install psycopg2-binary**.

Comment: I request an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`psycopg2` is a wrapper around the [`libpq` C library](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/libpq.html), and so it requires that library (plus other [pre-requisites](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#prerequisites)) to be installed before you can successfully run `pip install psycopg2`. The errors you see is probably related to that.

There's an alternative, which is to use the `psycopg2-binary` [wheel](https://pythonwheels.com/) package, which comes pre-packaged with its own version of C libraries (including `libpq`), meaning you don't need to go through all the pre-requisite steps.

```
$ pip install psycopg2-binary
```

The only cavaet is that `psycopg2-binary` is not recommended to be used in production environments.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```sh
pip install psycopg2-binary --user
```