# Create a new app in YII

Tags: php, macos, yii, osx-lion

I'm trying to generate a new app in Yii 1.1.12 with MacOsX 10.7.4 with the following code:

> yii/framework/yiic webapp testapp

And it throws out the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libssl.dylib
>   Referenced from: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib   Reason: Incompatible library
>   version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but
>   libssl.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8 Trace/BPT trap: 5

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find an answer in this post
[rails - postgres error: Reason: Incompatible library version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127486/rails-postgres-error-reason-incompatible-library-version-libpq-5-dylib-requ)

Though it was a problem related to yii.

Sorry