# Rails: Installing PG gem on OS X - failure to build native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, macos, rubygems

It seems many others have had problems installing the pg gem. None of the solutions posed for others have worked for me.

I have tried to install the pg gem and postgres.app. The pg gem won't install. The first error I get is:

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.

The installation advice about pointing my gem install to the config for pg fails with the following error message (which many others on this forum have encountered):

```
Failed to build native extensions... Results logged to /Users/melanie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

I don't know how to find or access this log file to search for further clues.

I also get an error message (command not found) when I try using the sudo apt-get install command. I've scoured this forum for the last 6 hours, trying each piece of advice to get pg working with my rails project.

I can't find advice about how to change a path, or specifically, what change is required.  My `which pg_config` returns a file source. I've used that with a command to install pg using that config. It fails.

There are so many people that have had trouble with this. Many answers suggest homebrew. I've had to remove that because it threw up other issues.

Comment: Hey, a couple questions that will help down the road:

- You're on Mac, right? Right went wrong with homebrew? (ps, as you noted, apt-get is just for Ubuntu (and its Debian-based cousins))

- what postgres version do you have? try running `psql -v` in your shell.

- what ruby version are you running? It looks like 1.9.3, but what does `ruby -v` give you?

Comment: I should add, that my psql is added in: /Applications/Postgres-1.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql ; exit;
psql (9.3.0)
but which psql returns: usr/bin/psql

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for looking at this. My psql is v 9.3.0 and ruby is v 1.9.3

Comment: See @paninapress's answer for Postgres.app. It worked great for me and doesn't require installing another instance of Postgres.

Answer (score 480, accepted):

Same error for me and I didn't experience it until I downloaded OS X 10.9 (Mavericks). Sigh, another OS upgrade headache.

Here's how I fixed it (with homebrew):

- Install another build of Xcode Tools (typing `brew update` in the terminal will prompt you to update the Xcode build tools)
- `brew update`
- `brew install postgresql`

After that `gem install pg` worked for me.

Comment: After two days of headache trying to fix my Rails db following Mavericks upgrade, this fixed it for me, many thanks.

Comment: This worked for me too - on a fresh Mavericks install. Thanks!

Comment: If you have permission issue when using Home Brew, use the script at this link https://gist.github.com/rpavlik/768518/download#

Comment: Thanks so much for this, perfect fix after Yosemite upgrade headaches.

Comment: Still working. Project is on Ruby 2.2.0 to support an old-ish app, but all the same THANK YOU.

Comment: I just tried `brew install postgresql` then `gem install pg` and it had worked for me! :)

Comment: 1. `brew update`
2. `brew install postgresql`
3. `gem install pg`
4. `bundle install`

Comment: Yep, worked perfectly for me after having had so much trouble to this point.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Fixing the error: An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling. Works for my MacOS 10.14.6

Comment: Wow, yep this solution definitely did it even in 2023. Thank you!

Answer (score 234):

If you are using Ubuntu try to install following lib file

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and then

`gem install pg`

worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. Am using ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Great! worked for me on Ubuntu Desktop 13.10. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 12.10!

Comment: Just make sure you type it correctly. Its not `libpg-dev`;  Its a Q not a P! It took me 10 minutes to figure that out the hard way.

Comment: For Amazon Linux it's `yum install postgres-devel`

Comment: Worked for me on #!11.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14!!

Comment: could you please explain why does it work and how you figured out it's going to work?

Comment: For CentOS `yum install postgresql-devel`

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and had this same problem happen, except I'm using `rvm` and `bundle` to install gems. Tried `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` and then ran `bundle install` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 50):

I am using OS X Mavericks (version 10.9)

and when I run the above I got the following message: If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed.

So I run the following command:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

and this worked for me, I hope this helps someone :)

Comment: +1, I tried others, but finally I got pg installed by gem with this solution.

Comment: +1, likewise, this was the solution for me as well, where my postgresql was already installed via brew.  Thanks Jon for the post.

Comment: n.b. If installing as root (for whatever reason), sudo goes *before* the variable: `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`

Comment: Actually, I need this every time I run `bundle install` so I've put it inside `~/.bash_profile` as an export :)

Answer (score 47):

Ok I also had this problem (psql is v 9.3.0 and ruby is v 2.1.2) and the solution that worked for me was setting the bundle config settings first:

```
bundle config build.pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

This answer finally helped me figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9235107/3546680

Comment: This method is **preferred** if you use postgres.app. Using Homebrew may fix the native extension problem, but having two postgres applications will create conflicts (like port allocation) See also Sayanees' answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569031/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-on-mavericks

Comment: This is definitely the right answer for Postgres.app.

Comment: Works well on Mojave, tried successfully few minutes ago.

Answer (score 23):

I tried everything for hours but the following finally fixed it (I'm on OS X 10.9.4):

1. Install Xcode command line tools (Apple Developer site)
2. brew uninstall postgresql
3. brew install postgresql
4. ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

Comment: Thank You. I had use sudo for step 4, is that a bad thing? How can I avoid it?

Comment: @Roy - glad to help :) -  should be fine,  probably want to avoid using sudo as I believe it will install it for all users, but if you're the only user on the system than its probably not that big of a deal.

Comment: `brew uninstall postgresql` and `brew install postgresql` are not necessary steps on OS X 10.10 and 10.11. Just `gem uninstall pg` (and remove all versions), then make sure you `bundle` or `gem install pg` again, and native extensions will be rebuilt with the new command line tools for this OS X version.

Answer (score 8):

easy step

1. `brew install postgresql`
2. `gem install pg -v 'your version'`

Answer (score 6):

Similarly, after installing Mavericks `bundle update` was throwing an error on the pg gem, which is only used on production and not locally.

I use Brew to manage my packages and postgresql was already installed, but still I was getting the 'no pg_config' error.

The fix was to just `brew uninstall postgresql`, then `brew install postgresql`. After which I was immediately able to successfully run `bundle update`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the “correct” answer would be to first configure PATH correctly for Postgres.app by adding the following to `~/.profile` (`.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile` if using ZSH):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

Then open a new tab or window in terminal and install the `pg` gem with:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

Documented here:

- https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html
- https://postgresapp.com/documentation/configuration-ruby.html

Answer (score 6):

On OSX with Postgres installed in /Applications, I simply run the following command (change **0.20**  & **9.4** according to your version)

```
gem install pg -v '0.20' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

You should have :

> Building native extensions with:
>   '--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config'
>   This could take a while... Successfully installed pg-0.20.

Comment: Can you explain why we had to use the hyphen 2 extra time before the argument is actually provided?

Answer (score 4):

running `brew update` and then `brew install postgresql` worked for me, I was able to run the `pg` gem file no problem after that.

Comment: This is the one on modern systems at least (e.g. macOS Big Sur).

Answer (score 3):

I spent a day on this and here's how I got it fixed:

I found that global value of build.pg was set to: `/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config` 
and that was not where postgres was installed.

I fixed it with replacing the value of build.pg to: 
`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.4/bin/pg_config` 
which is where my postgresql installation is.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=`which pg_config`
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
I found some lack of library for PostgreSQL on the system.
Only two steps solved it:

`brew install postgresql`

Then run

`gem install pg`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are not interested to use `brew`.

1. Download `PostgreSQL` application.
2. Follow the macOS default instruction to install it.
3. It is advisable to run `PostgreSQl`.
4. Run `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=`/path/to/postgress/in/your/applications/folder/`

   - For example, in my machine it is
     `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem and i solved

```
gem update --system 3.0.6
```