# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pg, osx-mavericks

I'm attempting to run `bundle` in my Rails project on OSX 10.9. It fails when getting to the `pg` gem with this error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_w32_wrap_io_handle()... no
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-fast-math'
compiling pg.c
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-fast-math'
pg.c:272:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PQlibVersion' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
               ^
In file included from pg.c:48:
In file included from ./pg.h:17:
In file included from /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1167:21: note: instantiated from:
# define INT2NUM(v) INT2FIX((int)(v))
                    ^
pg.c:272:9: note: instantiated from:
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
               ^
pg.c:272:17: note: instantiated from:
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
                       ^
pg.c:375:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_OK'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_OK", INT2FIX(PQPING_OK));
                                                      ^
pg.c:375:56: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_OK", INT2FIX(PQPING_OK));
                                                              ^
pg.c:377:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_REJECT'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_REJECT", INT2FIX(PQPING_REJECT));
                                                          ^
pg.c:377:60: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_REJECT", INT2FIX(PQPING_REJECT));
                                                                  ^
pg.c:379:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_NO_RESPONSE'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_RESPONSE", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_RESPONSE));
                                                               ^
pg.c:379:65: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_RESPONSE", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_RESPONSE));
                                                                       ^
pg.c:381:56: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT));
                                                              ^
pg.c:381:64: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT));
                                                                      ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [pg.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Also make sure that you've upgraded Xcode to re-install command line tools on Mavericks. 
In terminal type:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then follow the prompts.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server." From the CLI installer. Further research showed that Xcode 5 comes default with CLI tools. Sayanee's answer worked for me.

Comment: @JosephJuhnke I had the same issue. You can download and install manually from the Apple website. That worked for me.https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools#

Comment: Oddly, I recall that I had installed this software recently, but running the installer again as prescribed, fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: I had Xcode installed but had not agreed to the license.  Running sudo xcodebuild -license solved the problem.

Answer (score 47):

For me it worked when I did:

```
brew install postgresql
```

Comment: sometimes you need to 
    gem uninstall pg
after you brew install postgresql

Comment: worked for me! looks like using brew fixes the issue

Answer (score 27):

this worked for me with Mavericks and the Postgresapp:

```
gem install pg -v '0.17.0' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: worked for me too, for those copying this command pay attention to your Postgres.app name in the path

Comment: Postgres/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config for anyone installing with OS X Postgres app

Answer (score 14):

Try using the `--with-pg-config` argument:

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config
```

To show the path of the `pg_config`:

```
which pg_config
```

---

**For Ubuntu users:**

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 12):

For me using Mavericks, Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 2.0.0-p247, PostgreSQL 9.1, I needed todo this:

```
gem install pg -v '0.15.1' -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me to with version 9.3.1 on osx mavericks final

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Mac OS X 10.9.3 and Postgres.app version 9.3.4.2:

1) Install Postgres.app

2) `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`

3) `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'`

4) `bundle install`

Comment: What worked for me was `gem install pg -v '0.18.1' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 3):

I've just got it running by doing

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

after installing posgres using brew

Answer (score 3):

When i try to install

```
apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Failed to install, unmet dependencies problem, to solve

```
apt-get remove libpq5
```

then install

```
apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Finally solved the gem pg issue.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

gem install pg -v '0.18.1' -- --with-pg config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/pg_config

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure pg with your current version I used mine 9.4 version on Yosemite. Here is the following command

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

You should use your own version

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/(YOUR POSTGRES VERSION)/bin/pg_config
```

then do

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

`` An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.5'` succeeds before bundling. ``

I was able to fix this error by rolling back to Ruby v2.0.0. I was running Ruby 2.1.1, which is not supported for this debugger version. Be sure to check your ruby version if you run into this issue as well.