# Rails - OS Mavericks and postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-mavericks

Background - a few months ago, I purchased a new Macbook to replace an iMac.  When I restored my data from my old iMac to the new Macbook, I accidentally used `davidburton` as the user when on the iMac I was `burtondav`.

I was then not able to run postgreSQL or Rails.

I used this symlink command to fix it:

```
ln -s /Users/davidburton /Users/burtondav
```

But, yesterday I upgraded to OS X Mavericks.  Now I can't start postgreSQL or use Rails. Even after re-entering the symlink.

Is there any way to fix it???

If I have to re-install postgreSQL:

My postgreSQL files are in usr/local/var/postgres
I'm pretty sure I used homebrew to install it.

How can I re-install postgreSQL without loosing my data?

I was going to dump the whole database and reload after I reinstall postgreSQL. But I can't start postgreSQL in order to dump the data.

This is what I get:

```
$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
2013-10-24 15:30:07 GMT <  > %FATAL:  data directory   "/usr/local/var/postgres" has wrong ownership
2013-10-24 15:30:07 GMT <  > %HINT:  The server must be started by the  user that owns the data directory.
```

Should I change the ownership from burtondav to davidburton?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the owner of the postgres data directory:

```
chown davidburton /user/local/var/postgres
# or
sudo chmod ugo=rwX /user/local/var/postgres # You might want to change the permissions as your needs
```

(You might need to use `sudo`)

You didn't post the error when you try to start rails/postgres, maybe this question can help you: [ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569031/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-on-mavericks)

Comment: I changed the ownership.  Then I got `Permissions should be u=rwx (0700)`. So, I tried `$ chmod u=rwx, g=---, o=--- postgres`. But, I got `chmod: Invalid file mode: u=rwx,`

Comment: Try with `sudo chmod ugo=rwX /user/local/var/postgres`

Comment: Thanks - that got postgreSQL running.  Now I've got to get Rails working again.