# rails 4.2.0: can't install pg gem on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pg

I have recently tried to upgrade my rail 3.2* application to rails 4.2.*. But, I was stopped while installing the `'pg'` gem. When I googled it, the solutions which are mostly related to OSX only. But I'm using ubuntu 14.04. Need any suggestion for the below issue.

I have installed `postgresql 9.3.5` version on my machine.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@r4/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@r4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/pg-0.18.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: @mr-black please review my answer and accept it as the correct answer

Comment: in Ubuntu 22.04 (Windows 10 WSL2), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58961362/4023356) answer worked for me

Answer (score 32):

You need install the postgreSQL dev package with header of PostgreSQL

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

You may also try

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Comment: I have already installed those dependency packages. But, again I failed.

Comment: Did you look on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-gem-pg-on-ubuntu

Comment: sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib    ,this may work for you

Comment: Yes, I have already reviewed the given link and others too in SF. But it's not help to me in anyway.

Comment: First example worked great for me on one of our Ubuntu 14.04 servers, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Ran into this exact problem trying to `gem install pg -v 0.18.1` with postgresql 9.4 on ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev build-essential postgresql-server-dev-9.4
```

Basically I was missing `postgresql-server-dev-${version}`

In your case try

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev build-essential postgresql-server-dev-9.3
```

Comment: Thank you! Btw, sudo apt-get install libpq-dev was enough for me.

Comment: I have been wrestling this for several days and nothing helped until the `build-essential` package was installed (for `gem pg 0.21`).. I didn't see that anywhere else, so thank you!

Comment: Although just tried with `apt-get install libpq-dev gcc make` rather than the full `build-essential` and that worked as well

Answer (score 0):

Follow this command on ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev postgresql-server
sudo -u postgres createuser -s $(whoami); createdb $(whoami)
gem install pg
```