# Error occured when installing postgres gem on rail on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I'm learning to use ruby on rails on windows 8.1. I got stuck when I had to install pg(postgres) gem. To be specific, this is the error:

Error: Error installing pg:

```
   Error: failed to build gem natve extension
   C:/Rails Installer/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
  checking for pg_config... no
No pg_confg... trying anyway. If build fails, please try again with --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
```

I'm stuck, any suggestion will help.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall pg ?

Comment: I tried that but I'm still experiencing the same problem... Help please

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify where the `pg_config` is located using the Windows command-line tool (source: https://superuser.com/questions/49104/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-an-executable-in-windows):

```
where pg_config
```

Copy the path returned and use it

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/path/found/for/pg_config
```

(based on [ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569031/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-on-mavericks/19569369#19569369))

Comment: I tried to locate pg_config, but the result is: could not find files for the given pattern,  so I think i have to reinstall Postgres...is that a good idea?

Comment: Yea, try reinstalling it

Comment: Hi, after the reinstallation, nothing has changed, what do you suggest I do now?