# error while deploying rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite, pg

I am new to rails and heroku 
i tried the following code to push my app to heroku

```
    rails new snippets
    cd snippets
    git init
    git add .
    git commit -m "initial commit"
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
    heroku create
    git push heroku master
```

but i get the following error

```
 An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot

    remote:        continue.
    remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
    remote:  !     
    remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
    remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
    remote:  !
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
    remote: 
    remote: Verifying deploy....
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to powerful-waters-8202.
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/powerful-waters-8202.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/powerful-waters-8202.git'
```

i modified my gemfile as::

```
group :devlopment, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

when i run bundle install
i get the following error

```
Installing pg 0.18.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150705-24664-1i1n8se.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/pg-0.18.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/pg-0.18.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

i tried using the command

```
gem install pg -v '0.18.2'
```

and now i get the following error

```
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

here's my database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

and my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
###################################################################################
group :development, :test do # <<<< :development, not devlopment
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


##################################################################

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

can anyone help me out with this issue??

Comment: Are you on Linux(Ubuntu)?

Comment: i am using  Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS @Pavan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some good advice here already, but I'll add what I don't see mentioned.

My advice to you is to **use the same database in development as you do in production, PostgreSQL** . There are a number of reasons this is a good idea and you have just come across one, deployment headaches.

But let's say you stick with the different database types. This line in your gemfile looks strange to me-- "not devlopment"

```
# 
# 
###################################################################################
group :development, :test do # <<<< :development, not devlopment
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

I think you should try

```
# 
# 
###################################################################################
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thnaks a lot but i get the following error
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:

Comment: Did you bundle install after you changed the Gemfile? Must have changed something else too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to continue running SQLite in development, run

```
bundle install --without production
```

That will prevent Bundler from trying to install `pg`, but Heroku will install `pg` when you deploy, since they run `--without development,test`.

If you want to switch to Postgres locally, there's a lot of help around StackOverflow that I won't duplicate here:

- [How to install PostgreSQL's pg gem on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-postgresqls-pg-gem-on-ubuntu)
- [Installing PG gem on OS X - failure to build native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-on-os-x-failure-to-build-native-extension)
- [ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569031/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-on-mavericks)
- [Can't install pg gem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335750/cant-install-pg-gem-on-windows)

Comment: thanks @kristjan
i looked at the posts and tried to do implement
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
gem install pg 
but i still get the error as
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot remote: continue. remote: Make sure that gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10' succeeds

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned ***Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS***, try the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and then

```
gem install pg -v '0.18.2'
```

***Update:***

You should also change the ***adapter*** to ***postgresql*** for ***production*** in your `database.yml`

```
production:
adapter: postgresql
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

Comment: thanks @pavan 
but i get the following error
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before

Comment: In production? Please update your code with `database.yml` file.

Comment: thanks @pavan Please have a look at  the updated question

Comment: @pokiri Might be the `.sqlite3` extension for database file still causing you that error i guess. Try changing it.

Comment: thanks @pavan 
i created another project without .sqlite3 extension
 rails new -d postgresql hero
and it worked
but can u please suggest me the changes i need to make to my current project with the error as i described above

Comment: @pokiri Try with `.sql` extension for db file.

Comment: i changed the extension but i still get the  same error @pavan