# Cannot push my ruby app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sqlite, rubygems

I'm trying to post my demo app on heroku(from ruby tutorial), but I face the error of incorrect `git push heroku master` implementation:

```
Counting objects: 129, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (114/114), done.
Writing objects: 100% (129/129), 119.95 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 129 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..                                                                                       [173/194]
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.7.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.3
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.2
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.3
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.3
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.5
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.3
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.6.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.3
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.3
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.0
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.3
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.5.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.3
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.1
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.4
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.2
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.2.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.2
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.3
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.15
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.3
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_32f45e65619752c6e5c6598bfc3ced31/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_32f45e65619752c6e5c6598bfc3ced31/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_32f45e65619752c6e5c6598bfc3ced31/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_32f45e65619752c6e5c6598bfc3ced31/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.7.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.3
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.2
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.3
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.3
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.5
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.3
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.6.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.3
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.3
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.0
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.3
remote:        Installing execjs 2.5.2                                                                                                                          [56/194]
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.3
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.1
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.4
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.2
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.2.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.2
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.3
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.15
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.3
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_32f45e65619752c6e5c6598bfc3ced31/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_32f45e65619752c6e5c6598bfc3ced31/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_32f45e65619752c6e5c6598bfc3ced31/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_32f45e65619752c6e5c6598bfc3ced31/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to hopehope.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/hopehope.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hopehope.git'
azureuser@host:~/railstutorial_apps/demo$
```

(Also, the app launches on azure virtual machine without any error)
I've already tried to install sqllite separately (successful), but even after installation of sqllite I have the same error :(

The sqlite3 gem in Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.10'
```

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233141/error-while-deploying-rails-app-to-heroku/31234187#31234187

Answer (score 3):

in your gemfile add gem 'pg' as production group because heroku support postgresql

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

and add `adapter: postgresql` your database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: database_name_production
```

Answer (score 2):

Heroku doesn't support sqlite3, hence it won't have the library files required to install the sqlite3 gem.

You need to add sqlite3 to a development block in your Gemfile so that it won't get installed during deployment.

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Also on a side note make sure your application is running as expected using postgresql as well. Personally I suggest the same type of DB for development as well, so that there won't be any surprises when you transfer your application to production.