# gem install pg fails on OSX 10.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mavericks

when running bundle install (or gem install pg) i get the following error i have already tried fixing the xcode command line tools

```
/Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

- Ruby 2.0.0
- Rails 4.0.2
- OSX 10.9.1

Comment: A comprehensive answer is provided on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-on-os-x-failure-to-build-native-extension/60039365#60039365.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just had this same problem today and this answer solved it for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19620569/91970

Hope that helps.

## Summary

brew update

brew install postgresql

bundle install

Comment: thanks alot mate, worked a treat :)

Answer (score 5):

For reference, the code @marcamillion is linking to:

```
brew update
brew install postgresql

bundle install
```

Comment: Fantastic! This did the trick for me on a fresh install of OS X 10.10.5

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem .. I've modified Gemfile.lock and replaced pg (0.17.1) with pg(0.18.1) only.

Download PostgreSQL 9.4 and installed in system

use following command to install pg now

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```