# Cannot install PG gem on Mac OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, rubygems

I created a new rails app: rails new -d postgresql

However, I cannot get the pg gem to install. I had previously installed postgres using brew and it starts up automatically with my Mac.

I have tried several things posted here on SO. I am using ruby 2.0. When running bundle install, I get the error:

> Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.17.1/.gemtest
>
> An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.

I tried downloading the postgresapp, but when I try to start it, there is an obvious conflict b/c it says: could not start on Port 5432.  Not sure if this is causing an issue or not.

I also tried this:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-
config=/Users/david/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.3/postgresql.conf
```

And got the error: Failed to build gem native extension.

I am a fairly new programmer, so please be as detailed as possible in your response.  **Thanks!**

**FIXED**: I followed Justin's advice below and then did a restart.  After that,  I reran 'bundle install' and the pg gem finally installed!

Comment: This might sound crazy, but you should uninstall it via homebrew, then reinstall it. `brew uninstall postgresql` then `brew update`, then `brew install postgresql`. I had similar issues awhile ago and this did the trick.

Comment: @Justin thanks for the help; unfortunately, this did not work.  I am now trying to install from EnterpriseDB and see if that works.  Thanks :)

Comment: Try to update your Xcode Tools: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19620569/2456549

Comment: @Justin did that just now and am getting same error message above when trying to install the pg gem.  thanks again

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv?  You'd have to start much of your process all over if you're not, but they are worth it in my experience.

Comment: I have rvm installed, how do I know if I'm using it?

Comment: When I run psql --v, I get: "psql: FATAL: database 'david' does not exist"

Comment: There are a few different ways.  Try running 'which ruby', and if you get something that starts with ~/.rvm/rubies, then you're using rvm.  If you get something like /usr/bin/ruby, then you're not.  My guts says you're not, as you shouldn't need sudo to install any gems with rvm.

Comment: I got /.rvm.  And now it is **fixed**.  Not sure how that happened, but I restarted and reran bundle install and there it is.  Thank you both!

Comment: @Justin add as an answer, and I will mark it as the answer.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you should update your Xcode Tools since you are on MacOS. Here is a good post on that: [Installing PG gem on OS X - failure to build native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-failure-to-build-native-extension/19620569#19620569)

Then, I would go ahead and get a fresh instance of Postgres installed via `Homebrew`. First, uninstall it

```
brew uninstall postgresql
```

I would say run `brew update`, but the link I mentioned has you updating Homebrew. Now reinstall postgres with

```
brew install postgresql
```