# Mina deploy a rails project failed"Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mina

I use the mina to deploy a rails web app,but always have many error.
This is part of my mina's logs

```
Using mini_magick (4.5.1) 
Installing pg (0.18.4) 
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/www/sample_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160917-1997-acaacj.rb extconf.rb 
Cannot allocate memory - /usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160917-1997-acaacj.rb extconf.rb  2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/www/sample_app/tmp/build-14740431655892/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/www/sample_app/tmp/build-14740431655892/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
! ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
Unlinking current
OK
Connection to IP closed.

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 1 (4864)
```

I noticed `Cannot allocate memory` but I use `top` keep watch on the memory,only use about 50%(total 1G),and I am already run `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`,install pg succeed.  I can use `gem list`find it.
How to fix it?Thanks

Comment: any useful information in `gem_make.out`?

Comment: @Kris No it's cleand

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-on-os-x-failure-to-build-native-extension

Comment: @TanNguyenNhat Thanks,but my system is ubuntu,and already installed `libpq-dev`

Comment: It does not matter if you already installed pg or not because mina uses bundle install --path 'vendor/bundle' which means that it has separate gems for each of your application, not one is global.