# Postgres 'pg' gem cannot be installed

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have included the pg gem in the Gemfile with a "gem 'pg' ", but it is throwing the following error.

An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: What error does running `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` give.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: What is the error? What have you tried? There are several common solutions to this which you can find online, e.g. [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262312/installing-pg-gem-on-os-x-failure-to-build-native-extension)