# Cannot run "rails server" because of failure to install 'pg' in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pg

I am new to ruby on rails and I just downloaded a new Rails project directory that my friend sent to me. I put that directory on the Desktop and cd into it. I want to play with the code on my local host to learn from the code. But when I tried to run "rails s", it gives me the error saying that

```
"Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources
 Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."
```

So I ran "bundle install", then it gave the error that

```
"An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling."
```

I googled the problem for a while but I did not find any solution..
"rails s" stills works fine in my own project's directory. But how can I make it work in the directory I just downloaded? Am I supposed to do some other setup or installing?

Comment: Can you specify OS you are using? For instance installing gems on Windows it is very tricky. On linux box you need to install PostgreSQL header files, to compile gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I made development environment on my Mac.

Install PostgreSQL via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager `brew install postgresql`. This should install all necessary header files for gem compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed postgres on your local machine.

[gem install pg --with-pg-config works, bundle fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234960/gem-install-pg-with-pg-config-works-bundle-fails)

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --with-pg-config