# clang: error: unable to remove file: Permission denied when installing Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, rubygems

I'm trying to install Postgres on my machine. I'm following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234960/gem-install-pg-with-pg-config-works-bundle-fails/9235107#9235107).

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

I get the following errors

```
Last login: Sat Oct 24 19:55:19 on ttys004
~:$ gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151024-73485-3y70nd.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_w32_wrap_io_handle()... no
checking for rb_str_modify_expand()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
rm: pg_ext.bundle: Permission denied
rm: gvl_wrappers.o: Permission denied
rm: pg.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_binary_decoder.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_binary_encoder.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_coder.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_connection.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_copy_coder.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_errors.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_result.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_text_decoder.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_text_encoder.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_type_map.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_type_map_all_strings.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_type_map_by_class.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_type_map_by_column.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_type_map_by_mri_type.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_type_map_by_oid.o: Permission denied
rm: pg_type_map_in_ruby.o: Permission denied
rm: util.o: Permission denied
rm: .RUBYARCHDIR.time: Permission denied
make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)

make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
error: unable to rename temporary 'gvl_wrappers.o-4970f416' to output file 'gvl_wrappers.o': 'Permission denied'
1 error generated.
clang: error: unable to remove file: Permission denied
make: *** [gvl_wrappers.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/pg-0.18.3/gem_make.out
~:$
```

I tried changing the permissions of the folder `/Applications/Postgress.app/Contents/` using `sudo chmod -R 777` to no avail.

Comment: Do you have PostgreSQL installed on the system? If so, how did you install it?

Comment: I used this installation of Postgres (postgresapp.com)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't work for Mac. Here I share personal experience which is actual for nowadays and it just works.

**First step. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).** This is "the missing package manager for OS X". As claimed, you can do it just only with one command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

It will ask your password once, however after you can manage even more packages very easily. Once you installed Homebrew, run `brew doctor` to inspect your system and follow instructions. If you have brand new Mac, it may ask you to install XCode and build tools.

**Next. Install PostgreSQL.**

It is as simple as `brew install postgres`. This will take a while to download PostgreSQL and its dependencies. If you need exact version which is older that latest one, use `brew search postgres` to find exactly what you need.

**And finally. Install `pq` gem.**

There is no trick here:

```
gem install pg
Fetching: pg-0.18.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.18.3
1 gem installed
```

Cheers.