# Error with installing pg gem. OS X 10.10.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg

I have problems with installing pg gem. But bundle is successful.
Maybe smith with "Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)"

```
$ sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151216-5802-1na2dm0.rb extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--enable-windows-cross
--disable-windows-cross
--with-pg-config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
--with-pqlib
--without-pqlib
--with-libpqlib
--without-libpqlib
--with-ms/libpqlib
--without-ms/libpqlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
```

Anybody knows how fix it?

I tried ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install 
Didn't fixed.

Comment: please check `libpq` library is installed ? then you try `sudo gem install pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config` I am not give negetive vote

Comment: Try this `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`.

Comment: Thank you, 'sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg' it helps

Comment: @Зелёный Thanks! Your answer worked on my Mac (OSX Mavericks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I found a similar problem from 3 years ago. The installer can't find some of the config files it's looking for. This might work for you.

`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config`

If you're on MacPorts try this:

`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/pg_config`

However if you're using brew you can just run

`brew install postgresql`

[gem install pg --with-pg-config works, bundle fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234960/gem-install-pg-with-pg-config-works-bundle-fails)

Comment: are you sure about `/usr/pgsql-9.1/` ? As you can see OP already have installed `9.4`. Also you suggest to configure `bundler`, OP don't use a bundler.

Answer (score 1):

And If you are using PostgresApp here is the command:

`gem install pg -v '0.18.4' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_config`