# Postgresql gem install pg 0.18.4 passes, bundle install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Mac OS El Capitan

Bundle install fails with:

```
compiling pg_connection.c
pg_connection.c:2394:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gettimeofday' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                gettimeofday(&currtime, NULL);
                ^
1 warning generated.
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_result.c
compiling pg_text_decoder.c
compiling pg_text_encoder.c
compiling pg_type_map.c
compiling pg_type_map_all_strings.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_class.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_column.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_mri_type.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_oid.c
compiling pg_type_map_in_ruby.c
compiling util.c
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: file not found: dynamic_lookup
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pg_ext.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jmintz/Documents/LaunchAngels/radar/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jmintz/Documents/LaunchAngels/radar/vendor/bundle/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
```

...
...

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Running 'gem install pg -v '0.18.4' results in:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.18.4
Parsing documentation for pg-0.18.4
Done installing documentation for pg after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Yet running 'bundle install' again fails. Any suggestions? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling postgresql with homebrew with no luck

Comment: This SO thread might solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234960/gem-install-pg-with-pg-config-works-bundle-fails

Comment: Unfortunately I tried every suggestion in that thread and none worked

Answer (score 110):

I have got a similar error now on macOS Catalina, but I was not able to successfully run

```
gem install pg -v '0.18.4'
```

I found this issue in the `puma` gem (I know this is another gem) that helped me solve the issue: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2304.

There, I found this:

> Clang now enables `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` by default:
>
> Clang now reports an error when you use a function without an explicit
> declaration when building C or Objective-C code for macOS
> (`-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` flag is on). This additional
> error detection unifies Clang’s behavior for iOS/tvOS and macOS 64-bit
> targets for this diagnostic. (49917738)

And this:

```
gem install puma:4.3.5 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

So, I was able to build `pg` with:

```
gem install pg -v '0.18.1' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Comment: This also resolved the issue with pg 0.18.4 in MacOS Big Sur 11.0 Beta

Comment: The following worked for me: `gem install pg -v '0.18.4' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Comment: Thank You! Another Big Sur user rescued - works for pg 1.2.3. and Postgres 13

Comment: Worked like a charm in Catalina, thank you!

Answer (score 26):

The same issue has been faced with all the gems that rely on native extensions such as `pg`, `puma`, `ffi`, etc
I have solved them by passing `-- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

ex:

- `gem install pg -v '0.18.4' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`
- `gem install ffi -v '1.12.2' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`
- `gem install puma -v '4.3.1' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"`

Comment: this worked for me - changing the `config` value suggested by @haley-mnatzaganian did not work for some reason

Comment: confirmed working on Big Sur with ffi 1.9.23

Answer (score 15):

I had to combine Benito's answer and jasonm's answer like below before running `bundle` (credit to Unixmonkey):

```
bundle config build.pg '-- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"'
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to make a minor change to get this to work:

`bundle config build.pg '--with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"'`. The build options needed to be passed in without the additional `-- ` prefix. See https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html#BUILD-OPTIONS for more info.

Comment: on macOs Monterey I had to go into `~/.bundle/config` and change it to `BUNDLE_BUILD__PG: "--with-cflags='-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration'"` -- the `bundle config` command did not properly escape the quotations.

Comment: For me this worked after removing single quotes: ```bundle config build.pg --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an an answer, as such, but it may point you in the right direction... If indeed gem pg has successfully compiled, as you have indicated... Then it maybe that your Ruby project isn't referring to the correct gemset, somehow. As it appears it is attempting to install it again when you bundle install, this should not happen if pg has been compiled and installed in your current gemset. Are you using RVM on your system? Can you also provide more output?

Comment: Good thought but as far as I can tell they're the same: jmintz-laptop:radar console$ which gem
/Users/USER/.rbenv/shims/gem
console$ which bundle
/Users/USER/.rbenv/shims/bundle

Answer (score 0):

Answer was installing Postgress.app and running

```
  bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=[Path to pg_config] before bundling
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me on sierra:

```
gem install pg -v '0.18.3' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config
```