# rails pg_config path not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

I installed postgresql on my macbook via postgresql Graphical installer (http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/). Now I want  to configure pg in my rails project but I dont know where can I find pg_conf path.

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=<path to pg_config>
```

Comment: well you can simply add gem 'pg' in your gemfile

Answer (score -1):

simply add `gem 'pg'` in your gemfile. and let `bundle install` do the magic

**update**
may be this will help too. [gem install pg --with-pg-config works, bundle fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234960/gem-install-pg-with-pg-config-works-bundle-fails)

also if you only want `pg_config` path, then try `which pg_config` in your terminal. it will give you  its path.

Comment: yes but when I do "bundle install" I receive this error: No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config

Comment: I have a macbook air with OSX

Comment: did you try brew install postgresql